# My App working fine in Samsung but acting weird in HTC Desire S?

Tags: android, cordova-2.0.0

I have created an app demo app using cordova2.7 the app only contains a search box and two buttons in header and the same in the content field. When run the app in Emulator its working fine and then i tried to run it in Samsung mobile its working fine but when i tried to run it in HTC Desire S when i try to enter character to search element its  dispalys some white box above the header and when i try to enter the character in the serach field that i have in the content field it does not show the keypad.Please refer the snapshot I have uploaded below from HTC Desire S [image]

Answer (score 0):

Use RIPPLE, an extension to GOOGLE CHROME, which has inbuilt facility to simulate for different devices. You can get the idea from there.

Although, myself being a PhoneGap developer too, it is quite difficult to deal with all the devices. So your design must be Responsive !

Comment: Mastermind can you elaborate what is RIPPLE and how to use by giving any link please

Comment: [LINK](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc?hl=en) This is Ripple.

Comment: You can alternatively try Intel's XDK ! here is the [link](http://xdk-software.intel.com/)

Comment: hey i install the RIPPLE but when I try to Enable its showing nothing but when I try to open other sites like google or other its working fine can you tell me whats thew problem

Comment: Done but still not working do i have to copy the folder in the RippleSites in the c drive

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32793/discussion-between-mast3rmind-and-neerav-shah)