# Popup menu scroll with the page in jquerymobile

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova-2.0.0

I have create an popup menu in my app the problem with it is when i open the popup menu and then scroll the page the popup menu also scrolls up with the page even i tried using  data-dismissible="false" but nothing happen still the problem remains same.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an easy fix for this problem. Just prevent page scrolling when popup is active.

Working **`jsFiddle`** example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/aJChc/

For this to work popup needs to have an attribute: **`data-dismissible="false"`** it will prevent popup closure when clicked outside of it. Another attribute can be used: **`data-overlay-theme="a"`** it will color popup overlay div. That is a DIV that covers screen when popup is opened and prevents popup closure.

And this javascript will work on every possible popup:

```
$(document).on('popupafteropen', '[data-role="popup"]' ,function( event, ui ) {
    $('body').css('overflow','hidden');
}).on('popupafterclose', '[data-role="popup"]' ,function( event, ui ) {
    $('body').css('overflow','auto');
});
```

Comment: Thanks hey I have one more issue when run this app on ma HTC device its not working properly but when I run it on Samsung it working fine here is the link of ma question http://stackoverflow.com/q/17439797/2307391

Answer (score 1):

For me this method didn't work, it works on browser but not in Phone Gap application.
So I resolve it in this way:

```
$('#Popup-id').on({
   popupbeforeposition: function(){
      $('body').on('touchmove', false);
   },
   popupafterclose: function(){
      $('body').off('touchmove'); 
  }
});
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

if body scrolling is not prevented, try below. in my case i was using boilerplate.css so the preventing the body scrolling not worked.

```
 popupafteropen: function (e) {
               $('html').css('overflow', 'hidden');
            },
            popupafterclose: function (e) {
                $('html').css('overflow', 'auto');              
            }
```